# Selenium or WebDriver api?

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver

I will start using JBehave Web to create tests for a web applications, I've been checking and I saw that Selenium now integrates WebDriver api besides the original one from Selenium.

My question is, which one should I use? The application needs to be tested on Firefox and Internet Explorer and has some Ajax functionalities (although nothing too complex)

Also any reference to some good tutorial or book would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whichever you feel more comfortable with.  The WebDriver API has only recently settled down in Selenium 2.0RC3, while the Selenium RC API hasn't been changed at all in at least a year.  artbristol is right that the RC API (what he calls 1.0) isn't being developed further, but it's not going away any time soon either.

As to books, there are two very good ones.  Both are great beginner’s books for Selenium and a great deal .  Both are available in paperback and as e-books.  And if you want to peek at them, both authors or their publishers offer partial downloads for free.  The e-book prices are very reasonable, and the paperback prices are competitive.

- David Burns’ [*Selenium 1.0 Testing Tools: Beginner’s Guide*](https://www.packtpub.com/selenium-1-0-testing-tools-beginners-guide/book), free sample at https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/0264OS-Chapter-6-First-Steps-with-Selenium-RC.pdf?utm_source=packtpub&utm_medium=free&utm_campaign=pdf
- Alan  Richardson’s [*Selenium Simplified - Automated Web Testing with Java and Selenium RC*](http://www.lulu.com/product/paperback/selenium-simplified/14939945), free sample at https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2l9DD6OObL9MGQ3NGU4ODYtZmJlYi00MGY1LWIwNDUtZmM2N2UxODU4OWNm&sort=name&layout=list&num=50).

Answer (score 2):

The old Selenium (1.0) API is not really being developed any more, it's all about WebDriver now in Selenium 2.0. I recommend it for future-proofing your code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, since the two projects (selenium and webdriver) are merged, the underlying infrastructure is the same. So you shouldn't gain speed by using one API instead of another. You should use the API you like most.

My opinion is that the webdriver API is more convenient. It's much more convenient to use objects and not write procedural code. It shortens your xpaths and makes code easier and much more elegant. Plus, it's easier to write page objects when your working constantly with objects.

Comment: No, the underlying infrastructure is completely different.  The "project merger" is a packaging thing only - there is VERY little common code between the Selenium RC and WebDriver APIs.